# CSS animate with jQuery width is 0% still visible

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to animate different areas. The view is as follows:
There are 5 area's: 
A, B, C, D and E.

3 of them can be visible at once. The animation works but when I hide the 2 areas that have to be 0% there is still a visible white line.

I tried fixing it with `margin-left: -4px;` But I don't think this is the right way.

In my example you can see the white lines when I turn off `margin-left`.

```js
    $('.EditJob').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.BNone').toggleClass('BGroot BNone');
      $('.CGroot').toggleClass('CKleiner CGroot');
      $('.EKlein').toggleClass('ENone EKlein');
      $('.ButtonHide').toggleClass('EditJobHide EditJob');
    });

    $('.CloseWorkItemPreview').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.BGroot').toggleClass('BNone BGroot');
      $('.CKleiner').toggleClass('CGroot CKleiner');
      $('.ENone').toggleClass('EKlein ENone');
      $('.ButtonHide').removeClass('EditJobHide');
    });

    $('.EditQueueItemPreview').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.AGroot').toggleClass('AKlein AGroot');
      $('.CGroot').toggleClass('CKlein CGroot');
      $('.DNone').toggleClass('DGroot DNone');
      $('.EKlein').toggleClass('ENone EKlein');
      $('.ButtonHide').toggleClass('EditJobHide EditJob');
    });

    $('.CloseQueueItemPreview').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.AKlein').toggleClass('AGroot AKlein');
      $('.CKlein').toggleClass('CGroot CKlein');
      $('.DGroot').toggleClass('DNone DGroot');
      $('.ENone').toggleClass('EKlein ENone');
      $('.ButtonHide').removeClass('EditJobHide');
    });
```

```css
.AGroot {
  background-color: #90C3D4;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.AKlein {
  background-color: #90C3D4;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.BGroot {
  background-color: #83CCC8;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.BNone {
  background-color: #83CCC8;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  //  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.CGroot {
  background-color: #83CC89;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  //  margin-left: -8px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.CKlein {
  background-color: #83CC89;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -8px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.CKleiner {
  background-color: #83CC89;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
  //  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.DGroot {
  background-color: #CCC383;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.DNone {
  background-color: #CCC383;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  //  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.EKlein {
  background-color: #CCA983;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
  //  margin-left: -8px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.ENone {
  background-color: #CCA983;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  //  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="AGroot">
  <div class="ButtonHide">
    <button class="EditJob">Edit</button>
  </div>
  Area: A
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>

</div>

<div class="BNone">
  <button class="CloseWorkItemPreview">Close</button>
  Area: B
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="CGroot">
  <div class="ButtonHide">
    <button class="EditQueueItemPreview">Edit</button>
  </div>
  Area: C
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="DNone">
  <button class="CloseQueueItemPreview">Close</button>
  Area: D
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="EKlein">
  Area: E
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfvrymwq/)

Comment: I've moved your Fiddle code into a Stack Snippet as Stack Overflow requires the code to be in the question itself (just in case the link were to die).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using `display: inline-block;` which will honour the whitespace between elements.

The simplest way to fix this would be to remove the whitespace from between the `div`s in your html.

```js
    $('.EditJob').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.BNone').toggleClass('BGroot BNone');
      $('.CGroot').toggleClass('CKleiner CGroot');
      $('.EKlein').toggleClass('ENone EKlein');
      $('.ButtonHide').toggleClass('EditJobHide EditJob');
    });

    $('.CloseWorkItemPreview').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.BGroot').toggleClass('BNone BGroot');
      $('.CKleiner').toggleClass('CGroot CKleiner');
      $('.ENone').toggleClass('EKlein ENone');
      $('.ButtonHide').removeClass('EditJobHide');
    });

    $('.EditQueueItemPreview').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.AGroot').toggleClass('AKlein AGroot');
      $('.CGroot').toggleClass('CKlein CGroot');
      $('.DNone').toggleClass('DGroot DNone');
      $('.EKlein').toggleClass('ENone EKlein');
      $('.ButtonHide').toggleClass('EditJobHide EditJob');
    });

    $('.CloseQueueItemPreview').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.AKlein').toggleClass('AGroot AKlein');
      $('.CKlein').toggleClass('CGroot CKlein');
      $('.DGroot').toggleClass('DNone DGroot');
      $('.ENone').toggleClass('EKlein ENone');
      $('.ButtonHide').removeClass('EditJobHide');
    });
```

```css
.AGroot {
  background-color: #90C3D4;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.AKlein {
  background-color: #90C3D4;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.BGroot {
  background-color: #83CCC8;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.BNone {
  background-color: #83CCC8;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  //  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.CGroot {
  background-color: #83CC89;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  //  margin-left: -8px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.CKlein {
  background-color: #83CC89;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -8px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.CKleiner {
  background-color: #83CC89;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
  //  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.DGroot {
  background-color: #CCC383;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.DNone {
  background-color: #CCC383;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  //  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.EKlein {
  background-color: #CCA983;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
  //  margin-left: -8px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.ENone {
  background-color: #CCA983;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 960px;
  width: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  //  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: 3s width linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="AGroot">
  <div class="ButtonHide">
    <button class="EditJob">Edit</button>
  </div>
  Area: A
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>

</div><div class="BNone">
  <button class="CloseWorkItemPreview">Close</button>
  Area: B
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>
</div><div class="CGroot">
  <div class="ButtonHide">
    <button class="EditQueueItemPreview">Edit</button>
  </div>
  Area: C
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>
</div><div class="DNone">
  <button class="CloseQueueItemPreview">Close</button>
  Area: D
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>
</div><div class="EKlein">
  Area: E
  <p>
    This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
  </p>

</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6yozxan/)

Comment: @seahorsepip Ya but your answer need more explanation I suppose.

Comment: I just didn't explain the white space between the html divs because removing white space between them is a bad idea. Whites-space can show up unexpected anywhere in a html document because of a crappy text editor as example. There's a reason why &nbsp; exists :P

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Works so much better :D

Answer (score 3):

The white lines are caused by the "display: inline-block;" property. By using inline-block you say them to behave similar to words and words do have white space in between them, right?. There are a few tricks to avoid this problem. The easiest one is to remove whitespace between the sectione, i.e. remove white space between  and  for each section. Removing the white space would make all sections together work like a single word [there is no white space between letters in a word, right? so your sections will become letters ;)]. So for example:

```
</div><div class="BNone">
```

or

```
    </div><!--

 --><div class="BNone">
```

would do just fine.

However you can take also a different approach - read a [great article on CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Answer (score 1):

It's because of display: inline-block.
Either set font-size: 0; or use floats.

Example with:

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/seahorsepip/mfvrymwq/3/